# How to open new window whenever new table row is clicked React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window.open

```
return (
      <>
        <div className='table-wrapper'>
          <Table
            onUserChange={this.onUserChange} columns={headerColumn} data={rows}
            rowsPerPage={50}
          />
        </div>
        {
          selectedUser && <GradeReportChart
            closeGradeReport={this.clearSelectedUser}
            selectedUser={selectedUser}
          />
        }
      </>
    )
```

GradeReportChart component fetches data and display it in the new window, using [react-new-window](https://github.com/rmariuzzo/react-new-window) library, which uses `ReactDOM.createPortal` API. I want to display datas for each row in the table in new window. But GradeReportChart component opens one window and change the content whenever new row is selected. I don't want that I want every row on the table when clicked to display the data in a new window. A quick fix may be mount GradeReportChart component whenever row is clicked, how can I do that? Or any way to open new windows in every new row click?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `GradeReportChart`. If someone else can help you, that good! If not, I could try to help but I'll need a live demo in order to debug it. You can use codesandbox.io.

Comment: `GradeReportChart` is my component which uses `react-new-window` library.